# How could I go about using two ListViews with a BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically, I want to be able to use two ListViews through my BaseAdapter class in the same activity.  The ListViews will be displayed side-by-side and each item within the ListView will contain multiple views (ImageView, TextView, etc.).

My main issue is retreiving/displaying data through the getView() method inherited from BaseAdapter.  How would I go about detecting which ListView is being updated through this method so I will know which code to call/update?  I've tried looking at the ViewGroup parameter in getView() hoping that it led me to the parent of the ListItem but the id it returns was different from my ListView's resource ID...in fact it wasn't even in my R.java file at all:

```
12-14 04:44:58.613: ERROR/ParentFromGetView(312): 16908298
12-14 04:44:58.623: ERROR/MyListViewId(312): 2131165191
```

I was *hoping* to do something like so:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.ListView1) {
        //Do stuff
    } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.ListView2) {
        //Do different stuff
    }
}
```

...but the Ids are drastically off as seen above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you use the same adapter instance for two different list views? Even if it's the same data, no reason for it to be the same adapter instance surely...

Comment: Well, I would like for them both to run on the same activity.  Currently I'm extending my activity as a ListActivity and I set my adapter accordingly.  The data is completely different.  Is there something here I'm missing...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share a `ListAdapter` between two `ListViews`.

> Well, I would like for them both to run on the same activity.

So?

> Currently I'm extending my activity as a ListActivity and I set my adapter accordingly.

That only affects one of the two `ListViews`, whichever one has the `@android:id/list` value. You need to create a second `ListAdapter` for use with the second `ListView`. You get the second `ListView` by calling `findViewById()`, and you associate the adapter with that `ListView` via `setAdapter()`.